# Separate array values PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to separate array values echoed from foreach loop

```
<?php foreach($qty as $qty2): ?> 
    <?php foreach($qty2 as $q): ?>
         <?php echo implode(",", $q); ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

> A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Without adding implode function, my values would normally like this

```
87 89 78
```

It looks confusing so I would like to output as

```
  87, 89, 78
```

or

```
  87 - 89 - 78
```

or

```
  (87)(89)(78)
```

The idea is to show the users that they are different values from array

The qty array

```
  Array ( [0] => Array ( [qty] => 24 ) [1] => Array ( [qty] => 24 ) [2] => Array ( [qty] => 24 ) )
```

Now I tried this

```
   <?php foreach($qty as $qty2): ?> 
      <?php foreach($qty2 as $q): ?>
          <?php echo $q . " , " ; ?>
       <?php endforeach ?>
   <?php endforeach ?>
```

Result

```
  24 , 24 , 24 ,
```

There is always a trailing comma at the end

Any Ideas?

Comment: can you post your array $qty  ??

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `implode` on each element, on the iteration.

Just gather all the elements first inside a container, then use `implode()`.

```
<?php
$data = array();
foreach($qty as $qty2) {
    $data[] = $qty2['qty']; // gather all qty first
}
echo implode(', ', $data); // implode collected elements
?>
```

Or if `array_column` is available, you could use it too:

```
<?php

echo implode(', ', array_column($qty, 'qty'));

?>
```

Comment: I prefer the second option

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `join()` function to separate array values.. in join first argument is your `delimiter` and second is the array.

```
<?php 
  $qty = array(
    0 => array('qty' => 24 ), 
    1 => array('qty' => 24 ), 
    2 => array('qty' => 24 )
  );

  $arr = array();
  foreach ($qty as $q) {
    $arr[] = $q['qty'];
  }

 /// used delimiter ','
 echo join(',', $arr);
 echo "<br>";

 /// used delimiter '-'
 echo join('-', $arr);

?>
```

This will output

```
24,24,24
24-24-24
```